# How do you set a text's, that is overlaid over an image, opacity to 0 when the image is hovered over?

Tags: html, css

Ok I tried to set the text in a span and when the div (consisting of the image and the text in it) was scrolled over it would set the span opacity to 0. It is not working though, and here is my code.

HTML

```
<div id="phild">
     <td class="bio"> <img class="bio" src="phil.jpg" />
        <span id="phils"><h2 id="philh">Phil</h2></span>     
     </td> 
</div>
```

CSS to make the image opacity:1 when hovered

```
div#phild :hover{
opacity: 1;
transition: all .2s linear;
}
```

CSS to make the text opacity:0 when the entire thing (image and text) is hovered over

```
div#phild:hover span#phils{ 
opacity:0; 
}
```

Comment: So you want to text to be hidden?

Comment: Yes, so basically opacity 0

Comment: Can you give us the related HTML you have set up for this; the `<img/>` and text container tags?

Comment: you can try `display:none;` instead of `opacity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text is on top of the image, you can't use `img:hover` for your desired effect because when your cursor is on the text, it doesn't register as hovering the image. You could put the image and text inside something, and then have the text disappear when the parent is hovered

```css
.bio {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
.bio img {
  display:block;
}
.bio span {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}
.bio:hover span {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bio">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is what I was looking for. Could you please explain why it works?

Comment: `.bio:hover span` selects `span` elements inside elements with a class of `bio` when those with class `bio` are hovered. Since both the `img` and the `span` are inside `.bio`, if you hover over either one you are hovering over bio, so the styles defined for `.bio:hover span` apply

Answer (score 0):

So long as you`selectors` are correct, the following should work all the way back to IE 6:

```
img.bio:hover{
opacity: 1; /* css standard */
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* internet explorer */
}
```

Comment: This solution modifies the `<img/>` tag to be opaque on hover.

Comment: Hence the fact I said "As long as your selectors are correct" .. Without seeing the raw HTML one can only speculate ..

Comment: True. I didn't make the connection, hopefully other readers will. :)

Answer (score 0):

There a number of ways to do this. Assuming your text follows your `img` element, you can use the `hover` pseudo-class and [`adjacent sibling selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to target the text and apply your CSS.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bio {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

img:hover + .bio {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  <span class="bio">Text Here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I tried this but it didn't work exactly.. is the div{ display:inline } part necessary? other than that have exactly what you have